# :nth-child related only to specific class or element

Tags: css, css-selectors

it's possible assign :nth-child only to specific element, without count other element in the middle (ex http://jsfiddle.net/MgC4v/ with <*br>).

```
<p>1</p>
<br>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>

p:nth-child(3) {
    background-color:red;
}
```

the red line is the second one, not the third..thanks

Comment: Nth-child will select the element (specified by the nth value) that is directly under the parent. Therefore in your example nth-child is working correctly as the 2nd P tag is the third element. Nth-of-type would specifically count the selector only so would do what you need here.

Comment: Thanks Harry. But doesn't work with class.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgDev

Comment: Nth-of-type doesn't work off of element classes, it looks at the element specified (i.e.) P tag. If you have to use element.class I'd look to jQuery or set a parent div with a class wrapped around the elements then use nth-of-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Will select only third `<p>` element :) , was this your question ?

see http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-of-type
your example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DxGos

Comment: http://cdpn.io/KgDev doesn't work with class... the paragraph without class is in the count.

Comment: It doesn't work the way you try. the selector is nth-of-type, not nth-of-class :), it will add nth-of-type and class in checking if selector matches http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/lsvfo

Answer (score 0):

```
.slide:nth-child(2 of .active)
```